# SSRS 2016 - ReportViewer Not Landing on Proper Folder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am using an IFrame to render the SSRS Report Viewer.  It keeps landing on the Home folder instead of the specific folder for my reports.   I tried setting the folder in the URL but it did not make a difference.  I would appreciate any help.

HTML with URL:

`<iframe src="http://ServerName/Reports/ReportViewer.aspx?/ReportFolderName&rs:embed=true"  sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" id="activityFrame" style="width:100%; height:600px;"  frameborder="0"></iframe>`

PS The report viewer does open but it keeps landing on the Home folder.  I want it to land on a specific folder to make it easier for the users.

Comment: I've not tried this but can you not just use a clean URL without calling reportviewer? `http://ServerName/Reports/browse/ReportFolderName`

Comment: I have tried that and it does not work.

Comment: "does not work" isn't very helpful, what happens when you try this format?